# Fetch columns by their names from an SQL database

Tags: sql, r, sqldf, r-dbi

I have a `data.frame` stored in an `SQL` database, created with the `dbWriteTable` function of the `R` `sqldf` package.

I was wondering whether there is a way to fetch specific columns by their names from this `data.frame` in this SQL database.

For fetching rows by their names, this code  works:

```
#let's say the row names I want to select from the data.frame are in a vector called selected_row_names, where the data.frame is called df and the SQL database is called db
query_text <- paste("('",paste(selected_row_names,collapse="', '"),"')",sep="")
query_expression_text <- paste("select * from ",df," where row_names in ",query_text," order by row_names",sep="")
selected_df = dbGetQuery(db, query_expression_text)
```

My question is whether there's anything equivalent for selecting columns by their names?

If I try this code, where my selected column names are: "col-1T-A_m1" and "col-1T-A_m2":

```
query_string <- paste("select col-1T-A_m1, col-1T-A_m1 from ", df, sep="")
selected_df  <- dbGetQuery(db, query_string)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : error in statement: unrecognized token: "1T".
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running raw SQL queries, then you should be able to simply specify the column names you want after `SELECT`, e.g.

```
query_string <- paste("select col1, col2, col3 from ", df)
selected_df  <- dbGetQuery(db, query_string)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error message: Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : error in statement: unrecognized token: "1T". My query is: "select col-1T-A_m1, col-1T-A_m2, from df"

Comment: You need to escape the column names because there are spaces.  So try this: `select \`col-1T-A_m1\`, \`col-1T-A_m2\`, from df`